# How to specify priority fee and max fee per gas in Geth' JSON-RPC API?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, json-rpc, sendtransaction, eip-1559

A legacy transaction can be created with the following parameters through the `eth_sendTransaction` API:

```
params: [{
  "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
  "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
  "gas": "0x76c0",
  "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000",
  "value": "0x9184e72a",
  "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
}]
```

But what parameters are expected for an EIP-1559, specifically for the priority fee and max fee per gas?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am also interested how to deal with it.

Comment: @BogdanGainusa, yes, let me post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can either use `max_gas_fee` or `maxGasFee`.

The following works for me:

```
"params": [{
  "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
  "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
  "gas_limit": "0x76c0",
  "priority_fee": "0x0",
  "max_gas_fee": "0x9184e72a000",
  "value": "0x9184e72a",
  "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
}]
```